# Slow scrolling over the controls whose mouseOver state is changed

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Say i have five button controls placed in scrollviewer, out of those i have changed the mouse over state from template of last two buttons, now the problem is when i scroll over those three unmodified buttons scrolling is done very smoothly, but when the scrolling comes to last two template edited buttons and as the cursor comes over them, scrolling done very badly and slow.. Suggest something to get out of it.. It may be because when the same time scrolling going on and also the mouse over state hits so its slow.. Template editing is done in Assets/resourceDictionary.xaml

Comment: Can you share the actual template and edited template? Whether last two Buttons has fixed height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something - scrollViewer Scloll Started event, when you scroll, that event fire, then code at there something it lapse the mouseover events of controls and again back when scroll copleted